# How would I make a rectangle move every second in a WPF app in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, loops

I have a WPF app and I would like to change the position of a rectangle every second for an infinite amount of time (or until the application is closed)

Right now I have this

```cs
while(true)
{
     rect.Margin = new Thickness(rect.Margin.Left + 10, 0, 0, 0);
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

but this seems to just hang the application because it just delays the application by 100ms every single update

I want a while true loop that wont hang the application and fires every 1 second

Comment: I've also tried System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000) and System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000).Wait() but they appear to do the same thing

Comment: And yes I know I put 100ms instead of 1000ms in my code.

Comment: Use a DispatcherTimer.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from the little bit of code that you shared.  But it is most likely because your `while` loop is on the UI thread, so when you call `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)`, you are putting the UI thread to sleep and therefore it visually hangs.  The same will occur when you call `Task.Delay` with `Wait()` because it will synchronously run, and hold up the UI thread.

Instead, try using async/await.  This will free up the thread and allow other operations to perform on the same thread while the code is on the `await` line.

```
private async Task MyWhileLoopMethod()
{
    while(true)
    {
        rect.Margin = new Thickness(rect.Margin.Left + 10, 0, 0, 0);
        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

You will need to make every call up the chain async/await as well.  So for example, if you had a Button_Click event that triggered this rectangle movement, then at the top of the chain you would do this:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await MyWhileLoopMethod();
}
```